# Unable to access value from `Transformations.map` in unit test

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

To give some background to this question, I have a ViewModel that waits for some data, posts it to a MutableLiveData, and then exposes all the values through some properties. Here's a short gist of what that looks like:

```
class QuestionViewModel {

    private val state = MutableLiveData<QuestionState>()

    private val currentQuestion: Question?
        get() = (state.value as? QuestionState.Loaded)?.question

    val questionTitle: String
        get() = currentQuestion?.title.orEmpty()

    ...
}
```

Then, in my test, I mock the data and just run an assertEquals check:

```
assertEquals("TestTitle", viewModel.questionTitle)
```

All of this works fine so far, but I actually want my fragment to observe for when the current question changes. So, I tried changing it around to use `Transformations.map`:

```
class QuestionViewModel {

    private val state = MutableLiveData<QuestionState>()

    private val currentQuestion: LiveData<Question> = Transformations.map(state) {
        (it as? QuestionState.Loaded)?.question
    }

    val questionTitle: String
        get() = currentQuestion.value?.title.orEmpty()

    ...
}
```

Suddenly, all of my assertions in the test class have failed. I made `currentQuestion` public and verified that it's value is null in my unit test. I've determined this is the issue because:

- I can mock the data and still get the right value from my `state` LiveData
- I can run my app and see the expected data on the screen, so this issue is specific to my unit test.

I have already added the `InstantTaskExecutorRule` to my unit test, but maybe that doesn't handle the `Transformations` methods?

Answer (score 4):

I recently had the same problem, I've solved it by adding a mocked observer to the LiveData:

```
 @Mock
 private lateinit var observer: Observer<Question>

 init {
    initMocks(this)
 }

 fun `test using mocked observer`() {

    viewModel.currentQuestion.observeForever(observer)

    // ***************** Access currentQuestion.value here *****************

    viewModel.questionTitle.removeObserver(observer)
 }

fun `test using empty observer`() {

    viewModel.currentQuestion.observeForever {}

    // ***************** Access currentQuestion.value here *****************
 }
```

Not sure how it works exactly or the consequences of not removing the empty observer the after test.

Also, make sure to import the right Observer class. If you're using AndroidX:

```
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
```

Comment: It works because Transformations don't work without an observer. When you reference the LiveData<Question> property in your view, you typically observe it, and if you're using Data Binding then the code to observe it is written for you.

Answer (score 1):

Luciano is correct, it's because the LiveData is not being observed. Here is a Kotlin utility class to help with this.

```
class LiveDataObserver<T>(private val liveData: LiveData<T>): Closeable {
    private val observer: Observer<T> = mock()
    init {
        liveData.observeForever(observer)
    }
    override fun close() {
        liveData.removeObserver(observer)
    }
}

// to use:
LiveDataObserver(unit.someLiveData).use {
    assertFalse(unit.someLiveData.value!!)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing the `.value` on the it variable.

```
private val currentQuestion: LiveData<Question> = Transformations.map(state) {
        (it.value as? QuestionState.Loaded)?.question
    }
```